# Is it possible to create an SQL transaction that rollbacks on syntax errors?

Tags: mysql, transaction, syntax, error-handling, rollback

In may day-to-day job, I often have to create SQL files containing minor changes (no DDL operation usually) in order to migrate those to production databases easily.

The problem is, even with syntax checking, I often run into issues with syntax errors, which I notice only when I try to run said queries.

Even if I wrap those in transactions, insertions and deletions made before the point of the error are performed regardless.

Is there a way to rollback on syntax errors in a transaction?

Comment: Maybe the best option is by checking it using a test db

Comment: You could switch to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @McNets that's what I'm usually doing but it easily becomes tedious because of certain factors.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how/why would that help?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, DDL is transactional, and any error causes the transaction to be rolled back. But that is off-topic.